# Angularfire2 Ionic3

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to use Angularfire2 on an Ionic3 app.

When installing it `npm install angularfire2`, I get a deprecation warning:

`npm WARN deprecated angularfire2@5.2.1: AngularFire has moved, we're now @angular/fire`.

But if trying to install the new @angular/fire `npm install @angular/fire` I see that every version requires an @angular/core >= 6.0.0 -which is greater than the Ionic3 supported on (i.e. "5.2.11").

So, my question is how can I make use of a non-deprecated angularfire2 lib on Ionic3?

Thanks

Comment: It says warning but does it still install? If so you can try using as is. Otherwise you could just try with angularFire v4

Comment: Hi, Chris, absolutely, it does get installed, and I could try using it regardless of its deprecated status. That's the plan for now.

Comment: Yes this is as much as you can hope for, and part of the nature of constantly evolving javascript ecosystem. I've added an extra comment in the answers section, but feel free to create another question if you do come unstuck with the specific implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A deprecation message doesn’t always mean the package or version is unusable; it may mean the package is unmaintained and will no longer be updated by the publisher.
>   https://docs.npmjs.com/using-deprecated-packages

This leaves a few options, either upgrade angular so that recommendations are met, downgrade angularfire to a version that did hold support for your version of angular, or try to use as is and hope for the best.